# MongoDB/Mongoose how to manage incrementation of some Number fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, increment

I'm currently working on an API and I need the users to have at least 4 fields of number which will increase over time. Some of them might be 15000/hour, some of them 500/hour, some will be negative like -8000/hour. How should I handle such data storage using Mongoose? What kind of properties should these user model fields have? If you can provide me a simple Mongoose model for such data storage, I would be happy.

Should I have something in back-end just to increase (or decrease) these fields of users? Or does MongoDB/Mongoose have something to provide this feture? Also, how should I show these fields increasing on the web page? Should I always get the increased fields of user every few seconds? Or should I just use JavaScript on front-end?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It would depending on what you would want to achieve with your data, at the end of the day.
To keep track of all changing logs, persisted in its **respective array**, then **bucket pattern** would best solve your problem [bucket pattern explanation][1]
[1]: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-bucket-pattern
, else just **ordinary field manipulation** should solve your problem.

Schema design for implementation of both, [bucket pattern] and [field manipulation] are shown as follows:

If you plan to keep track of all your changing logs, then **bucket pattern** is your best bet, your schema could look like this:

```
  const mongoose = require('mongoose')
  const { Schema } = mongoose

  const numberLogSchema1 = new Schema({
      field1: [
        {type:Number}
      ],
      field2: [
        {type:Number}
      ],
      field3: [
        {type:Number}
      ],
      field4: [
       {type:Number}
      ]
   })

   module.exports = mongoose.model('numberLogs1',numberLogSchema1)
```

And its corresponding would look like this:

```
   router.post('/numberLog', async (req, res) => {
      try {
          const saveNumberLog = await numberLog1.updateOne(
            { _id: numberCollectionIdhere },
            {
                $push: {
                    field1: req.body.fieldLogValue
            }
        })
         res.json(saveNumberLog)
     }catch (err) {
         res.json({
            message: err
       })
     }
  })
```

Else if you just want to manipulate field values, at specific intervals from the frontend, using a **javascript timer** which could also be persisted to the database and fetched on a page Reload, your schema could look like this:

```
   const mongoose = require('mongoose')
   const { Schema } = mongoose

   const numberLogSchema2 = new Schema({
       field1: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          default: 0
       },
       field2: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          default: 0
       },
       field3: {
          type: Number,
          required: true,
          default: 0
       },
       field4: {
           type: Number,
           required: true,
           default: 0
       }
     })

  module.exports = mongoose.model('numberLogs2',numberLogSchema2)
```

And its corresponding route paths, could look like this:

```
  //if you intend to just increase the logvalue hourly 
  //without keeping track of it previous value then we use $inc
  router.post('/numberLog2', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const saveNumberLog2 = await numberLog2.updateOne(
        { _id: numberCollectionIdhere },
        {
            $inc: {
                field1: req.body.fieldLogValue
            }
        })
        res.json(saveNumberLog2)
      }catch (err) {
         res.json({
           message: err
      })
    }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I liked both ways to handle this problem but I think second options fits better for my system. Is this data model scalable? I mean when I have many users, each user will have at least 4 fields and each field will be needed to updated (or incremented) continuosly. If a user has 15000/hour addition for field1, then that makes 4.17/sec and this field1 should be increased 4.17 each second. Is this healty?

Comment: Yeah, mongodb is highly scalable and you can check out https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-scale for more information on mongodb